# JAXB2 map xsd:restrictions as subclasses and (un)marshall xsi:types

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2

I have been doing a lot of research trying to figure this out, but am
still unsuccessful.

I have a number of XSD that follow this schema:

**Simple_Identification.xsd**

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Base_3039.xsd"/>
       <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Simple_A.xsd"/>
       <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Simple_S.xsd"/>
       <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Simple_N.xsd"/>
       <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Simple_V1.xsd"/>
       <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Simple_L.xsd"/>
       <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Simple_V.xsd"/>
       <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Simple_C.xsd"/>
       <xsd:simpleType name="Simple_Identification">
               <xsd:restriction base="Base_3039"/>
       </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

where for example **Simple_S.xsd** looks like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="./Simple_Identification.xsd"/>
    <xsd:simpleType name="Simple_S">
      <xsd:restriction base="Simple_Identification">
           <xsd:minLength value="14"/>
           <xsd:maxLength value="14"/>
     </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Eventually, I would like to be able to generate XML  files that contain
tags looking like this:

```
<Identification xsi:type="Simple_S">XYZUVW</Identification>
```

For now, without enabling mapSimpleTypeDef, I am able to
marshall/unmarshall XML files, ignoring the simple types like Simple_S.

After enabling mapSimpleTypeDef classes are generated for the simple
types. Simple_Identification is mapped to a class containing a Base_3039 field. And Base_3039 class contains a String field.  However, the classes for the different subtypes of Simple_Identifications do not extend Simple_Identification but only contain a field of type Simple_Identification, which does not help when marshalling/unmarshalling.

For example, when unmarshalling this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="...">
  <Identification>EDS-200708021031-950012222329</Identification>
  <Time>2007-08-02T10:31:44.449+01:00</Time>
  <Function>9</Function>
  <Sender>
    <Identity xsi:type="Simple_S">111111380002111</Identity>
 </Sender>
</Header>
```

the value of Identity is unmashalled to a Simple_Identification  object not to a specialized Simple_S object. Moreover, if I marshall back all xsi:type attributes are lost in the generated XML.

So, basically, my question is how can I properly unmarshall and generate XMLs containing xsi:types. Are the schemas I'm working with not appropriate for doing this? Is xsd:restriction not interpreted as a type of inheritance by JAXB?

Note that the XSDs are not mine to modify, I just have to work with them to properly read and generate XMLs.

Thanks for taking the time to help me figure this out!

-Anca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAXB does support `xsi:type`, but you will only see different sub-classes generated (and instance objects created) when dealing with complex types, not simple types.

Restricting a simple type using only a facet does *not* lead to the creation of a new class with JAXB. That is because, purely in object-oriented terms, the derived class would look exactly the same as the super-class anyway.

Comment: Hi xcut- Thanks for your answer, it makes things a lot clearer. In this case, I guess, there is no way I could generated XML files looking like my example above based only on the XSDs I have.

In order to be able to generate something containing xsi:types I'm thinking about using JDOM to construct the XMLs and then validate against the schemas.

Do you have a better suggestion?